# Google map in a div loaded by ajax

Tags: jquery, jquery-gmap3

Is it possible to show a google map in a div loaded by aAJX using gmap3?

I tried to put the script in the page that is loaded but i achieved no sucess..

I load the page using this script

```
 $(document).on('click','.letra',function(){
            var y = $(this).attr("data-letra");
        $.ajax({
            type: 'post',
            url: 'pesquisa-cidade.php',
            data: {'letra' : y},
            success: function(retorno){
                $("#aqui").html(retorno);


            }
        })
    });
```

can anyone help me?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible.

First option: in your `retorno` put HTML and JS code together...

Second option: put only HTML in your `retorno` but after adding html call function that will bind gmap to your div. For example:

```
 success: function(retorno){
     $("#aqui").html(retorno);
     $('#map').gmap3();
 }
```

Note here that you must have element with id `map` in your `retorno` if you want to add gmap to it, and you have to import gmap before calling this function